# Join two Pandas Dataframe and keep duplicate columns only from first Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I need to join two dataframes based on key columns. Both the dataframe have many common columns (other than Key column), I just need one instance of these common columns ( let's say from left dataframe). How to do this?

```
merged_df= pd.merge(df1, df2, on=["key"])
```

My thought: Since common columns have _x and _y after join. I am planning to drop all columns which have _y in the end.

Please let me know if any better way to do this?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example and the matching expected output

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use [`union`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.union.html) along with the `suffixes` parameter of [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) :

```
#keep the left-most columns
merged_df = (pd.merge(df1, df2, on="key", suffixes=("", "_"))
               [df1.columns.union(df2.columns)]
)

print(merged_df)

    id  key lower_letter name upper_letter
0  197    2            f  qux            D
1  197    2            g  qux            D

#keep the right-most columns
merged_df = (pd.merge(df1, df2, on="key", suffixes=("_", ""))
               [df1.columns.union(df2.columns)]
)

print(merged_df)

    id  key lower_letter name upper_letter
0  196    2            f  qux            D
1  125    2            g  foo            D
```

*Inputs used :*

```
np.random.seed(123)

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "key": np.random.randint(1, 6, 4),
    "id": np.random.randint(100, 200, 4),
    "name": ["foo", "bar", "baz", "qux"],
    "upper_letter": list("ABCD")
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "key": np.random.randint(1, 6, size=4),
    "id": np.random.randint(100, 200, size=4),
    "name": ["baz", "qux", "foo", "bar"],
    "lower_letter": list("efgh")
})
```

Comment: In this example all the columns are same. but there are some unique columns as well between the two dataframes which I need in my merged dataset.

Also, what does IIUC mean?

Comment: [IIUC](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=IIUC), I updated my answer! Can you check it out ? If it's still not good, you should **make an example**.

Comment: You beat me with your edit ;)

Comment: That means we may thought on the same solution, I'm very flattered! Thanks mozway ;)

Comment: @Timeless this gives me results, only thing is column order is not preserved. When I see results first column is columns number 32 from first dataset. any way to maintain order ? ( all columns from first dataset coming first and then any additional columns from second dataframe in same order)

Comment: Use `[df1.columns.union(df2.columns, sort=False)]`.